# NoModuleFoundError: No module named 'distributed'

Tags: python, dask, joblib

I'm trying to implement dask on a cluster that uses SLURM. The client is successfully created and scaled, however, at the line

```
with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
```

the operation gets the worker timeout error and I get the following error from the slurm jobs:

```
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'distributed.cli.dask_worker' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distributed')
```

I have checked to make sure that distributed has been installed on the cluster's nodes and I am able to import it into python without any issues. Does anyone know why distributed is causing issues?

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this might be of interest https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2036

Comment: @IronMan I actually did come across that issue, and tried doing the dask[complete] but that didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure PYTHONPATH is positionned in the same way when logging onto the nodes and when submitting the task through srun or sbatch ? (try sbatch --export=ALL)

Comment: Creating a new conda environment seems to have fixed the issue. I have a feeling it had something to do with package version mismatches between workers and scheduler. Now I'm getting this error: "distributed.worker - WARNING - Heartbeat to scheduler failed
distributed.worker - INFO - Connection to scheduler broken.  Reconnecting..." but that seems to be a separate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a fresh conda environment with dask[complete] seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the `distributed` library installed.  This commonly happens for a few reasons:

1. You did `pip install dask` rather than `pip install dask[complete]` or `conda install dask`
2. You installed into a different python executable running on your machine

   I see that you're using `/usr/bin/python3`.  To be extra safe try `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip dask[complete]`
3. Your worker machines don't share the same file system as your login nodes

Comment: As I said in the original post, I did ensure that distributed was installed on all the nodes. It seems to have been an issue with package locations/python paths though because using a conda env solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried all above but this one did it for me:

```
pip install distributed

pip install dask["complete"]
```

Also if your using pycharm just search these two and install them from interpreter setting